# How to filter/ find a match in a's href and then add a class into it with jquery

Tags: jquery, filter, custom-data-attribute, jquery-1.9

How can I filter/ find a match in a's href and then add a class into it?

For instance,

```
base_url = 'http://localhost/test/2013/js/data/';
var fragment = location.hash; // for an example - '#/news/manage?set=1&page=1';

var test = $(".button").filter("[href*='" + base_url + 'cms/' + fragment + "']");
test.addClass('hello');
alert($('.hello').attr('data-id'));
```

I get nothing.

html,

```
<li><a href="http://localhost/xxx/cms/#/news/manage?set=1&page=1" class="button" data-id="100">1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/xxx/cms/#/news/manage?set=1&page=2" class="button" data-id="200">2</a></li>
```

I should get **100** I thought!

Comment: Do you have this section placed under document.ready? it should work http://jsfiddle.net/djCUP/

Comment: Side note, instead of `.attr('data-id')`, you can do `.data('id')`

Comment: Are there no other ".hello" nodes in your DOM besides the ones to which you dynamically add the CSS class?

Comment: sorry, it works now. i think there are some bugs in my main codes. thanks for the help.